# How to use custom renderers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am creating a custom editor, but am not sure how to use it in xml. I tried reading tutorials online but none really explain what to use as the local variable in the xml.

I tried using `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SocialNetwork.Renderers;assembly=SocialNetwork.Renderers"` but it doesn't load and when I type `<local:MessageEditor/>` there is no `Text =` or any of those options

The path to the editor is `SocialNetwork.Renderers`

Custom Editor Code and the path is shown (PCL class)

```
namespace SocialNetwork.Renderers
{
    public class MessageEditor : Editor
    { 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `assembly` should simply be `SocialNetwork`. So use this:

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SocialNetwork.Renderers;assembly=SocialNetwork"`